# /etc/init.d/nis missing on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nis

I'm trying to setup NIS on a machine. All instructions always expect /etc/init/nis to exist as at the end of configuration one is expected to restart the service using that. For me it doesn't exist. I did try an `apt remove nis; apt install nis`, it made no difference.

```
root@vplab030:/var/log# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
root@vplab030:/var/log# 


root@vplab030:/var/log# apt show nis
Package: nis
Priority: extra
Section: universe/net
Installed-Size: 638 kB
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Mark Brown <broonie@debian.org>
Version: 3.17-32ubuntu6
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78), libgdbm3 (>= 1.8.3), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libslp1, netbase, make, rpcbind (>= 0.2.0-6ubuntu1), lsb-base (>= 3.0-6), hostname (>= 2.98), upstart (>= 0.9.7-2)
Pre-Depends: debconf (>= 0.5.00) | debconf-2.0
Suggests: nscd
Conflicts: netstd (<= 1.26)
Download-Size: 152 kB
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Description: clients and daemons for the Network Information Service (NIS)
 This package provides tools for setting up and maintaining a NIS domain.
 NIS, originally known as Yellow Pages (YP), is mostly used to let
 several machines in a network share the same account information, such
 as the password file.

root@vplab030:/var/log# ls -l /etc/init.d/ypbind /etc/init.d/nis
ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/ypbind: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/nis: No such file or directory
root@vplab030:/var/log#
```

yp.conf:

```
root@vplab030:/var/log# cat /etc/yp.conf 
#
# yp.conf   Configuration file for the ypbind process. You can define
#       NIS servers manually here if they can't be found by
#       broadcasting on the local net (which is the default).
#
#       See the manual page of ypbind for the syntax of this file.
#
# IMPORTANT:    For the "ypserver", use IP addresses, or make sure that
#       the host is in /etc/hosts. This file is only interpreted
#       once, and if DNS isn't reachable yet the ypserver cannot
#       be resolved and ypbind won't ever bind to the server.

# ypserver ypserver.network.com

domain dev.domname.com server ds4
domain dev.domname.com server ds2

root@vplab030:/var/log# 

root@vplab030:/var/log# grep ypbind /var/log/syslog
Sep  9 12:49:30 vplab030 ypbind: Host name lookup failure
Sep  9 12:49:30 vplab030 kernel: [    5.630218] init: ypbind main process (830) terminated with status 1
Sep  9 12:49:30 vplab030 kernel: [    5.630240] init: ypbind main process ended, respawning
Sep  9 12:49:35 vplab030 kernel: [   10.700047] init: wait-for-state (autofsypbind) main process (1126) killed by TERM signal
Sep  9 12:49:35 vplab030 kernel: [   10.700660] init: wait-for-state (lightdmypbind) main process (1134) killed by TERM signal
root@vplab030:/var/log# date
Tue Sep  9 13:59:11 CDT 2014
root@vplab030:/var/log# 

root@vplab030:/var/log# service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  autofs
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ + ]  friendly-recovery
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  nxserver
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ + ]  rpcbind
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saned
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ + ]  udev
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ - ]  x11-common
root@vplab030:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not your fault, it's a bug in the documentation:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nis/+bug/1303717

The package uses upstart, which uses files in /etc/init/ rather than /etc/init.d/.